# Slow download issue on .Net Web Form Application using Microsoft Edge

Tags: c#, .net, download, microsoft-edge

I have a .net web form application (.net framework 4.7.2).

It runs on intranet.
Files downloaded from my application are very slow using Microsoft Edge.

- User edge version is 103.x
- Other intranet web application (not managed by me) works fine
- My edge version is 100.x and it works fine. Files are downloaded immediately

In my application there are different code blocks to manage download .. like this

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.txt");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(myContentByteArray);
Response.End();
```

or

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.txt");
Response.OutputStream.Write(myContentByteArray, 0, myContentByteArray.Length);
Response.OutputStream.Flush();
Response.OutputStream.Close();
Response.End();
```

or

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.txt");
Response.OutputStream.Write(myMemoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, myMemoryStream.GetBuffer().Length);
Response.OutputStream.Flush();
Response.OutputStream.Close();
Response.End();
```

or

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.xls");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myFile.Length.ToString());
Response.WriteFile(myFile.FullName);
Response.End();
```

I suppose that is a client issue (some security policies or other specific configuration).

But I should consider that my backend code is wrong.

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Please may you help me?

Comment: Could you please check if the user turns on Microsoft Defender SmartScreen in Edge 103 [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymrob.png)? If he does, will the download be faster if he turns off Microsoft Defender SmartScreen?

Comment: Thanks a lot @YuZhou. You are right, Microsoft Defender SmartScreen is the issue!

Comment: @YuZhou, in order to get web app acceptable from microsoft defender. did you know if there's some web server (or web application) configurations? Or should I ask to sys administrator for a specific configuration for Microsoft Defender (maybe through Intune)?

Comment: Actually it's an issue with Edge 103, I'll put it into an answer.

Comment: @YuZhou thanks again. Please, Do you have a bug issue official link?

Comment: Sorry it seems there's no public link of the issue tracker. Let's see what will happen in Edge 104.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an issue with Edge 103. Microsoft have became aware of the problem and started investigating. You can wait for the release of a new version of Edge.

Now we have a workaround: Setting the policy of [NewSmartScreenLibraryEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#newsmartscreenlibraryenabled)=0 (or [SmartScreenEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#smartscreenenabled)=0) will avoid the problem.